# pass record data to lightning component in lightning page in salesforce community

Tags: lightning-community, lightning-components

How to pass record data to lightning component in lightning page in salesforce community?

I want to create a button on A_Object's record detail page.It will be:
click it → open the lightning page(which is a Insert form for create B_Object's record) in my salesforce community
→set Input form default value with A_Object's record data

Now I know how to use quick action to get recordid and pass it to a lightning component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="newAcc" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="simpleNewAcc" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newAccError" type="String"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="record" 
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetRecord="{!v.newAcc}"
                      targetFields="{!v.simpleNewAcc}"
                      targetError="{!v.newAccError}" />

    <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="test__c">
        <lightning:messages />
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" value="{!v.simpleNewAcc.Name}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

The component like above is set in a community page.

Comment: What is your question here? Are you stuck somewhere, is there a specific issue that you are facing?

Comment: Thank you for comment!I edit the question. I dont know how to pass record data to lightning component in lightning page in salesforce community.

Comment: So are you trying to get the values populated in `simpleNewAcc` attribute as soon as you click on the button on Obj A's detail page?